# colnames(data.table): is the order always the same?

Tags: r

this is probably a very simple question but i've been working with SQL a lot recently & i'm a bit paranoid about the ordering of a "set" of data in R now.

```
dt<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(7,8,9))

vals<-data.table(cname=colnames(dt), val = sapply(colnames(dt), function(x) {min(dt[,get(x)])}))
```

am i safe to assume colnames(dt) will always have the same order? in this example, will the order of colnames(dt) always be a, then b, then c?

the goal is to get the right values associated with the right column names always.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the order will always be the same, as far as you don't add/remove columns in the data table.

Comment: thanks. i'm doing a loop & dt<-new data every iteration. after vals, i do rm(dt) & gc() then loop. does this ensure no copies, etc? & no complications for my purposes? thanks.